# How to integrate by parts ghost fields in electrodynamics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, dirac-delta-distributions, grassmann-numbers, ghosts

When applying Faddeev-Popov method to electrodynamics in the Lorenz gauge we obtain the ghost action
$$S=\int d^4xd^4y\bar\eta(x)\left(\partial^2\delta(x-y)\right)\eta(y),\tag{0}$$
where $\partial^2$ denotes $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu$ (I am omitting Lorentz indices just for notation simplicity). My question is how to show that the above expression can be written as
$$S=-\int d^4x\partial\bar\eta(x)\partial\eta(x).\tag{1}$$

**My attempt:**

Write
$$\bar\eta\partial^2\delta\eta=\partial(\bar\eta\partial\delta\eta)-\partial\bar\eta\partial\delta\eta-\bar\eta\partial\delta\partial\eta,$$
and neglecting the surface term,
$$S=-\int d^4xd^4y(\partial\bar\eta\partial\delta\eta+\bar\eta\partial\delta\partial\eta).$$
Once again,
$$\partial\bar\eta\partial\delta\eta+\bar\eta\partial\delta\partial\eta=\partial(\partial\bar\eta\delta\eta)-\partial^2\bar\eta\delta\eta-\partial\bar\eta\delta\partial\eta+\partial(\bar\eta\delta\partial\eta)-\partial\bar\eta\delta\partial\eta-\bar\eta\delta\partial^2\eta,$$
and after neglecting surface terms
\begin{align}
S&=\int d^4xd^4y\left[\partial^2\bar\eta\delta\eta+2\partial\bar\eta\delta\partial\eta+\bar\eta\delta\partial^2\eta\right],\\
&=\int d^4x\left[\partial^2\bar\eta\eta+2\partial\bar\eta\partial\eta+\bar\eta\partial^2\eta\right],
\end{align}
which does not look like (1). Moreover, the last integrand can be written as a total derivative $\partial(\partial\bar\eta\eta+\bar\eta\partial\eta)$, which result in another surface term and the last integral would vanish. Can I drop those surface terms? Then why am I not getting (1)?

Comment: The derivation from eq. (0) to eq. (1) is just integration by parts (dropping boundary terms).

Comment: Hi @Qmechanic That is what I am trying to do. But it seems I am not getting (1) as showed in my attempted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Qmechanic points out, in integration by parts, one drops all surface terms, since they correspond to evaluations out there, at infinity.

So, automatically dropping them off, in your expression, you slide down the straightforward banister,
$$ \int d^4xd^4y~~~\bar\eta(x)\left(\partial_x^2\delta(x-y)\right)\eta(y)  
=  \int d^4xd^4y~~(\partial_x^2\bar\eta(x))~ \delta(x-y) \eta(y) \\  =  \int d^4x ~(\partial_x^2\bar\eta(x))~  \eta(x)
  = -\int d^4x~\partial_x\bar\eta(x)\partial_x\eta(x). $$

Comment: Thanks! My bad notation, $\partial$, was my problem! Since the derivatives are with respect to $x$ all derivatives of $\eta(y)$ vanishes in my expressions.